# Find gradient and Hessian of $f(x,y):=\frac{1}{2} \|Ax-(b^Ty)y\|_2^2$

Tags: matrices, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, hessian-matrix, scalar-fields

> Given matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ and vector $b \in \mathbb{R}^m$, let $f : \mathbb{R}^{n+m} \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined as $$f(x,y) := \frac{1}{2} \|Ax-(b^Ty)y\|_2^2$$ where $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $y \in \mathbb{R}^m$. Find the gradient $\nabla f(x,y)$ and the Hessian $\nabla^2 f(x,y)$.

---

I tried to expand the expression for $f(x,y)$ and compute the partial derivatives with respect to $x$ and $y$ but I don't understand properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\def\bb{\mathbb}$
Combine the vectors $x\in{\bb R}^{n}$ and $y\in{\bb R}^{m}$  into a single long vector
$$\eqalign{
w = \pmatrix{x\\y} \in{\bb R}^p\qquad p=m+n \\
}$$
and define block matrix analogs of the standard basis vectors
$$\eqalign{
&&e_1 = \pmatrix{{\tt1}\\0},\qquad &e_2=\pmatrix{0\\{\tt1}}\\
&&E_1 = \pmatrix{I_n\\0_n},\qquad &E_2 = \pmatrix{0_m\\I_m},
\qquad 0_n\in{\bb R}^{(p-n)\times n} \\
&{\rm so\,that} \\
&&x = E_1^Tw, \qquad &y=E_2^Tw \\
}$$
The following vector will prove useful.
$$\eqalign{
h &= Ax - (b^Ty)y \\
 &= AE_1^Tw - (b^TE_2^Tw)E_2^Tw \\
dh &= AE_1^Tdw - (b^TE_2^Tdw)E_2^Tw - (b^TE_2^Tw)E_2^Tdw \\
 &= \Big(AE_1^T - E_2^Twb^TE_2^T - (b^TE_2^Tw)E_2^T\Big)\,dw \\
 &= M\,dw \\
}$$
Write the function in terms of these new variables and calculate its gradient.
$$\eqalign{
f &= \tfrac 12 h^Th \\
df &= h^Tdh \\&= h^TM\,dw \\&= (M^Th)^Tdw \\
\nabla f \doteq 
\frac{\partial f}{\partial w}
 &= M^Th \\
 &= \Big(AE_1^T - E_2^Twb^TE_2^T - (b^TE_2^Tw)E_2^T\Big)^Th \\
 &= \Big(E_1A^T - E_2by^T - (y^Tb)E_2\Big)\,
    \Big(Ax - (b^Ty)y\Big) \\
}$$
So that's the gradient vector.

I'll leave the Hessian matrix to you.

Comment: Thank you so much. ❤️

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming $f(x,y)=\frac{1}{2}|Ax-(b^Ty)y|^2 $ is the function  $$f(x,y)=\frac{1}{2}(Ax-(b^Ty)y)^T(Ax-(b^Ty)y)$$
So take the transpose and solve the equation and you get
$$f(x,y) = \frac{1}{2} (x^TA^TAx - 2y^T(y^Tb)Ax + y^T(y^Tb)(b^Ty)y)$$
Then you can take the partial of $f$ w.r.t.  $x$ and $y$.

After you get the gradient, derive the hessian by doing the same thing to the ${ \partial f'(x,y) \over \partial x}$ and ${\partial f'(x,y) \over \partial y}$